# How Come Setting a Canvas Text to (0,0) Coordinates Does Not Put It On Upper Left Corner?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using JavaScript to create a canvas element and put some text there. When I write this snippet of code:

```js
const canvElem = document.createElement("canvas");
canvElem.style.border = "1px solid black"
const ctx = canvElem.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, 50);

document.body.appendChild(canvElem)
```

It actually works as shown below:

[image]

The 0, 50 are the x & y coordinates so if I type 0, 0, it should put it in the upper right corner but instead it goes off screen as shown with this snippet

```js
const canvElem = document.createElement("canvas");
canvElem.style.border = "1px solid black"
const ctx = canvElem.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, 0);

document.body.appendChild(canvElem)
```

[image]

Why does it put it off screen?

Comment: Try it with 0, 5 and 0, 10 and 0, 15

Comment: The origin of the text is in the left top corner. The test is written left to right

Comment: It's to do with where the [text baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline) sits. You can change it with `ctx.textBaseline = 'top'` for example.

Comment: @Andy This seems to have solved the issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your right @KonradLinkowski , I guess i just had a mixup in my brain.